# Entity Framework schema errors when deploying to a remote server

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first

I've used EF code first to create a DB. Works great in dev. I copy it to a windows server 2003 box and I get these errors (listed below)

EF 5, .NET 4.0.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the .net 4 framework. as well as tested on other machines.

On my Windows Server 2008 box it works fine. On another 2003 box it does not.

To take MVC out of the equation, i built a simple console app that lists out some data from the db. - Same error there.

I had written everything in VS 2012 with .net 4.5 installed on the machine. I read that could cause an issue, so I re-wrote everything in VS 2010 targeting .net 4, and manually added the reference to the EF 5/.net4 dll. Same thing, works great on my 2 dev machines, and on the 2008 server, but not 2003.

**Error:**

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'. 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'. 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element.  The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces:  http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
```

Here's the stack trace (It's a MVC app)

```
[MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.]
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +8508793
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +181
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +211
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders) +295
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString) +48
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ModelMatches(XDocument model) +45
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +65
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +52
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +239
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.c__DisplayClass8.b__6() +19
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +117
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +186
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +118
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +190
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Kiosk.Controllers.KioskEventController.Index() in c:\Dev\hbkiosk\Kiosk\Controllers\KioskEventController.cs:23
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +240
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8836913
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Can you check the file version of entityframework.dll you are referencing? The NuGet package contains two versions: 4.4 for .NET 4 and 5.0 for .NET 4.5

Comment: It's 4.4. VS 2012 wanted to use 5 even after changing the target framework and uninst/reinst the nuget package, so i removed the reference and manually added the reference to the 4.4 dll. Verified that the output directory contained the 4.4 dll and the project still ran properly.

Comment: Try putting this attribute on your context class:
[DbModelBuilderVersion(DbModelBuilderVersion.V4_1)]

Comment: This resulted in the same error, HOWEVER - I ended up dropping/rebuilding the database and am now good. Maybe there is EF specific meta-data stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, EF stores your current model in the database so it can detect if it changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my connection string to have ef create the db fresh with the proper dll installed on the project. I then migrated the data from the old db to the new one.

My assumption is that the EF 5 code stored some meta data in the DB (although i couldn't verify this).  Since EF code first will create the db/schema if the database doesn't exist, I simply changed my connection string to a non-existant database, ran the project and let EF build the db, then migrated the existing data from the DB created by V.5 to the db created by v.4.

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean by "changing my connection string to have ef create the db fresh"? I'm having the same issue and this answer is pretty much the only place with a resolution

Answer (score 0):

I updated .NET Framework to 4.5 and it worked.