# Invalid Scheme issue when using EF 5 with .net 4.0 (MVC 4)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application that we developed in MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.0, and it worked fine using .Net 4.5. 
Then because the Client hosting does not support .NET 4.5, I needed to downgrade everything to .NET 4.0. I was getting an error

```
Could not load System.Net.Http library or one of its dependencies
```

until I created totally new solutions and projects, which all target .NET 4.0 and re-install all the required packages using NuGet.

Now again, everything is working fine locally, but when I deploy to the server I am getting the following error.

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Provider'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ProviderManifestToken'.
(0,0) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(0,0) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl.
```

Now I have made sure that all the libraries that I am using are targeting .NET 4.0. NuGet kept installing EF 5.0, but the library version reads (4.4) which is from my reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573176/entity-framework-schema-errors-when-deploying-to-a-remote-server) should be OK with .NET 4.0.

I do not know where I am going wrong but it's getting really frustrating, any help would be much appreciated. We are using EF 4.4 Code First (DbContext and

Also, not sure if this makes a difference, We are using CustomMembershipProvider, and it is working fine locally, we only using it for authentication at the moment. To take out of the equation, I took its configuration out of the Web.Config and still the same problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was in 2 things:

1. In one of the models (Classes) my work mate was using an Enum, which is not supported in EF 5.0 for .NET 4.0. This feature works for EF 5 on .NET 4.5 but not for .NET 4.0 and it was causing an issue.
2. The Model Checker was also failing when it tries to check the current Database state with my EF model. Although there were no changes, it was still failing just when checking. To fix it, I needed to change this line

`Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ChiptronicsContext>());`

to the following

`Database.SetInitializer<ChiptronicsContext>(null);`

You will find this line in Global.asax.cs

Effectively, this line was causing EF to check for the database and make sure that it is in Sync with my model, so I just needed to restore one of the databases that I have generated locally to the server, then just run it, and everything went smooth. 
Hope this can help someone else.